# error starting jupyter inside docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I successfully installed docker and nvidia-docker on ubuntu 18.04
I pull this image from NVIDIA's GPU cloud

```
https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:caffe
```

and ran it with this command

```
nvidia-docker run -it --rm -v /home/stefan/Dropbox:/data -p 8888:8888 nvcr.io/nvidia/caffe:19.03-py2 sh
```

The container gives me a shell prompt and it seems to work, for example

```
# nvidia-smi
```

results in

```
Sat Mar 30 21:03:30 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.39       Driver Version: 418.39       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 105...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 20%   30C    P8    N/A /  75W |    441MiB /  4038MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
```

It sees my wimpy gpu. I try to run jupyter with this command

```
#jupyter-notebook
```

but I get

```
[I 21:05:18.088 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "</usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/decorator.pyc:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1628, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1407, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 143, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 168, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I know jupyter is installed in the container because when I type

```
#jupyter --version
```

I get

```
4.4.0
```

Typing

```
# jupyter
```

gives

```
usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
               [--paths] [--json]
               [subcommand]
jupyter: error: one of the arguments --version subcommand --config-dir --data-dir --runtime-dir --paths is required
```

I have several notebooks in the host directory I attached to the container

```
# ls
NBA.ipynb  exponents.ipynb        hello_deep_learning-master
```

but nothing seems to work

```
# jupyter NBA.ipynb

Error executing Jupyter command 'NBA.ipynb': [Errno 2] No such file or directory


# jupyter notebook NBA.ipynb

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "</usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/decorator.pyc:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1628, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1407, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 143, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 168, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address


# jupyter-notebook NBA.ipynb

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "</usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/decorator.pyc:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1628, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1407, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 143, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 168, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I think it's a syntax issue because this works

```
  docker run -it --rm -v ~/Dropbox:/tf/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter
```

It starts the jupyter server in the container and in a browser I can open a notebook at 127.0.0.1 which shows a directory where I can see a folder named 'notebooks' which contains my Dropbox contents. Just as expected since I mounted my dropbox folder as a volume in the command above.

But if I type this

```
  docker run -it --rm -v ~/Dropbox:/tf/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter sh
```

I am in a shell but cannot start jupyter. I get the same error as I was before with the nvcr.io/nvidia/caffe image. How can I start jupyter AFTER I am in the running docker container shell?

Answer (score 30):

At the shell prompt of the container, I type

```
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root
```